# How to force asp.net MVC Intranet application , to connect to a different domain than the one it is installed under

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net MVC Intranet web application that uses windows authentication. On our development environment the asp.net MVC and the active directory were on the same machine, so users were authenticated against the AD by default. Currently on the staging server we have the following:-

1. Our AD is on a remote server and on a different domain.
2. I can only lo-gin to the asp.net MVC using the staging admin it is installed under.

So my question is how I can force asp.net MVC web application, to authenticate users on the remote server where the AD is installed, instead on the AD where the asp.net mvc is installed under?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a trust relationship between the domains?

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the Big Picture premise that your Dev, Stage, QA, Stress and Production environments are all separate environments that have separate AD domains then I would strongly recommend the following solution:  **Create Different users for each environment in each of the domains**.  Do not try to do a cross domain authentication or an ADFS solution just for Stage, QA, Stress.

You want the design to be like production and if you are not using cross domain auth or ADFS in production then do not use cross domain in QA, Stage, Stress either.
So in your situation I would create unique users in each of the AD environments (script them with PowerShell possibly).

Final Thought, Do you really need separate AD for each QA or Stage environment?  If the main AD had 3 groups called “MyAppStage”, “MyAppDev”, and “MyAppProd” could you accomplish what you are trying to do without using separate AD environments?